# Google Api Calendar If else ,done with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

So I'm doing Google Calendar Api, that shows all the booked things for that day. I'm trying to get this code to print 'Vapaa' (means free in finnish and is shown if there's nothing booked in that time) only once but still print the rest of the appointments that come later that day. Here's the code that does the if else

```
if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var when = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        var hs = addZero(when.getHours());
        var ms = addZero (when.getMinutes());
        var end = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
        var he = addZero(end.getHours());
        var me = addZero (end.getMinutes());
        var now = new Date();
        var hn = addZero(now.getHours());
        var mn = addZero (end.getMinutes());

        if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
        }

        if (when.getTime() <= now.getTime() && now.getTime() <= end.getTime()){
            appendPre(event.summary + '  ' +  hs + (':') +   ms + '' + (' - ') + '' +  he +  (':')  +  me + '');
        } else {
            appendPre('Vapaa');
            appendPre(event.summary + '  ' +  hs + (':') +   ms + '' + (' - ') + '' +  he +  (':')  +  me + '');
        }

        return;
    }
} else {
    appendPre('Ei varauksia');
}
```

Also the `appendPre` is printed to html with this code

```
function appendPre(message) {
    if (message != 'Vapaa'){
        var pre = document.getElementById('booked');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n' + '\n');
    } else {
        var pre = document.getElementById('free');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n'  + '\n');
    }
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
}
```

I'm so lost so any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`return;` stops right where it is and exits the function, so your for loop will only run once with the `return` in there.  See [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) for more info.

Typically, if you want to exit only the loop, but continue in the function (if you have code after it, it doesn't look like you've shown that here), you can use `break;`. If you want to skip the rest of the stuff in the `for` loop (nothing is shown in your example), but continue iterating onto the next entry, you can use `continue;`.  See [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) for more details.